# Problems with scaling RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made a layout with a RecyclerView where each item is an ImageView with a TextView under it with a shape under it to add borders to the item.

The problem is, in portrait orientation, the image doesn't fit the entire space while it does in landscape.

Portrait example:
[image]

Landscape example:
[image]

activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordlayout"  >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

recyclerview_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"  >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/freelancer_s_portrait"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_square"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/rampart_pt"
        android:padding="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"  />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_square"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Asana"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium.Inverse"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flIcon" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the scaleType property of imageview ,but the picture may be distorted.

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: Do you know why the view don't just resize its height down so the image don't need to stretch instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

If you use `wrap_content` the `ImageView` will have the height of the actual image jpg instead of your desired height.

However you may use your own height dps.